# What is the best way to work with another repository in my repository?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-push, git-pull

I have a repository that I'm working on, let's call it **Super**. I need code from an open-source repository, let's call it **Dep**, in Super's repository. I need to be able to pull from Dep's original repository in case there are any changes, and I need to be able to make additions to Dep's code and push them to Super's repository. **What is the best way to do this?**

I've tried looking at sub-modules but I can't make changes to the module and push them onto Super's repository. I also tried just cloning Dep into Super's repository, but then I can't pull from Dep's repository.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow. This question is very prone to receive opinion based answers, as you are asking "which is the best way to". Would you like to rephrase it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you fork **Dep**, so that you can make changes into it, make pull requests, etc.